# Appending text to input field on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put 3 or 4 buttons that would help registering users to enter their e-mail addresses. Basically what I need is when they click "@gmail.com" button, their address will be completed with that. I ended up with a code like this:

```js
function insertText(elemID, text) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
  elem.innerHTML += text;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Insert some text" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'Hello');">
</form>
```

However as you can try and see, it's not working when a user enters some text inside and clicks the button. I want to resolve this issue with minimum amount of script and preferably without jQuery.

Note: I will place this code snippet inside a block, but the textarea might be not in the same block. Is that possible to still make use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<textarea>` element uses `value` not `innerHTML`:

```
function insertText(elemID, text) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
  elem.value += text;
}
```

Comment: this is working perfectly fine, thanks for your help. but i'm unable to make it work in my page, since the text field is outside of the area i will put the code, in other words i won't create the text but will make use of an existing one. how can I achieve this?

Comment: "i won't create the text" - are you referring to a string or to the textarea element?

Comment: i meant textarea, sorry if I couldn't explain it well. I will put this script and the button on an existing page, so button and text area will be in different div's. I tried to put the button and script, and it didn't worked, so I think the reason is their placement. I think I have no choice of putting them together. If that gives a clue, I'm using Ultimate Member and trying to modify their registration form with buttons for common mail domains, which will be appended to the given text on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Change `elem.text` to `elem.value` in your code

```
function insertText(elemID, text) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
  elem.value += text;
}
```

Comment: this is working perfectly fine, thanks for your help. but i'm unable to make it work in my page, since the text field is outside of the area i will put the code, in other words i won't create the text but will make use of an existing one. how can I achieve this?